# Using apply and ggplot to make multiple bar charts in R

Tags: r, ggplot2, dplyr, apply

I have data from a survey (1300 rows and 12 columns), and I'd like to make bar charts for all columns (I've removed all NA values).

````
q1 <- rep(c("yes", "no"), 10)
q2 <- rep(c("no", "yes"), 10)
q3 <- 20:39
data <- cbind.data.frame(q1,q2,q3)```
````

I'm using the following code, but I cannot seem to get the right label for the x axis (which should just be the column name).

```
lapply(data[,c(1:3)], function(variable) ggplot(data = data,
                                     mapping = aes(variable)) + 
         geom_bar() + labs(x = variable, y = "count"))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One option to achieve your desired result would be to loop over the variable names and make use of the `.data` pronoun from `rlang` like so:

```r
q1 <- rep(c("yes", "no"), 10)
q2 <- rep(c("no", "yes"), 10)
q3 <- 20:39
data <- data.frame(q1, q2, q3)

library(ggplot2)

lapply(names(data), function(variable) {
  ggplot(
    data = data,
    mapping = aes(.data[[variable]])
  ) +
    geom_bar() +
    labs(x = variable, y = "count")
})
#> [[1]]
```

[image]

```
#> 
#> [[2]]
```

[image]

```
#> 
#> [[3]]
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

In `base R`, use `barplot` with `table`

```
par(mfrow = c(3, 1))
Map(\(x, y) barplot(table(x), xlab = y), data, names(data))
```

-output

[image]